# is using 'ANY' here necessary (sql)

Tags: sql

hey i'm new to the sql language 
i have a relation `Movie(title, year, length, inColor, studioName, producerC#)`

the question is (Which movies are longer than Gone With the Wind?)

i want to know if there a difference between these two answers and which one is correct and why

```
select title 
from movie 
where length>any(select length from movie where title ='gone with the wind')

select title 
from movie 
where length>(select length from movie where title ='gone with the wind')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many entries do you have in your table movie for title "gone with the wind"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length > ANY (<select>)` means that `length` needs to be higher than one (or more) of the values returned by the select. This select could return more than one value. Replacing it with `> (<select>)` is only possible if you know that select to be a singleton select (ie it produces only one row).

Answer (score 2):

If you have more one length for the `title ='gone with the wind'` then `Any` will help you find movies where length is greater among any one of those length in sub query.

```
select title 
from movie 
where length>any(select length from movie where title ='gone with the wind')
```

Second query will work out only if have only **one length** where `title ='gone with the wind'` else it will throw error `subquery returned more than one value`. It will fetch the movies where length is greater than the subquery result

```
select title 
from movie 
where length>(select length from movie where title ='gone with the wind')
```

If you have more than length for a single movie then choose the first query else use the second query.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the title is unique, then use:

```
select title 
from movie 
where length > (select length from movie where title = 'gone with the wind');
```

The use of `any` is a bit misleading because it implies that there could be more than one match.

If there is more than one match, I would use:

```
select title 
from movie 
where length > (select min(length) from movie where title = 'gone with the wind');
```

or:

```
where length > (select max(length) from movie where title = 'gone with the wind');
```

Depending on which I really mean.

Personally, I don't see any use for the keywords `any`, `some`, and `all` when used with subqueries.  I think the resulting queries are easier to understand using aggregations, which make the particular comparisons explicit.